# AJAX to upload Image using JSON not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using the code below to upload image files to my server. It is working well until it gets to the image selection.

When the image is selected it is split into two sizes (medium and small), also files movement is also working. However, I am not getting results using `AJAX.form req`.

I also want to store the address in a mysql table.

```js
 $(document).on('change', '#image_upload_file', function(){
                                var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');
                                       $('#update_dp').ajaxForm({
                                                url:'/auth/ajax/update_dp',
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                beforeSend: function() {
                                                progressBar.fadeIn();
                                                var percentVal = '0%';
                                                bar.width(percentVal)
                                                console.log(percentVal);
                                                                        },
                                                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                                                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                                                bar.width(percentVal)
                                                console.log(percentVal);
                                                                },
                                                success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                                                   obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                                                   console.log(html);
                                                    if(obj.status){
                                                            var percentVal = '100%';
                                                            bar.width(percentVal)
                                                            console.log(obj.image_medium);
                                                            $("#profile_dp>img").prop('src',obj.image_medium);
                                                                    }
                                                                        else {
                                                                                alert(obj.error);
                                                                            }
                                                                                },
                                                            complete: function(xhr) {
                                                             progressBar.fadeOut();
                                                             }
                                                            }).submit();

                                                        });
```

```css
 .progressBar {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E0E0;
  left: 0;
  padding:0px;
  margin-top:3px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
 }
 .progressBar .bar {
  background-color: #2FAF84;
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
 }
 .progressBar .percent {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 2px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

function createDir($path){
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        $old_mask = umask(0);
        mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE);
        umask($old_mask);
    }
}

function createThumb($path1, $path2, $file_type, $new_w, $new_h, $squareSize = ''){
    /* read the source image */$source_image = FALSE;

    if (preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $file_type)) {

        if (!$source_image = @imagecreatefrompng($path1)) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
        }
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($path1);
    }
    if ($source_image == FALSE) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }

    $orig_w = imageSX($source_image);
    $orig_h = imageSY($source_image);

    if ($orig_w < $new_w && $orig_h < $new_h) {
        $desired_width = $orig_w;
        $desired_height = $orig_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);
        $desired_width = ceil($scale * $orig_w);
        $desired_height = ceil($scale * $orig_h);
    }

    if ($squareSize != '') {
        $desired_width = $desired_height = $squareSize;
    }

           $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
// for PNG background white-----------
    $kek = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $kek);

    if ($squareSize == '') {
        /* copy source image at a resized size */imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    } else {
        $wm = $orig_w / $squareSize;
        $hm = $orig_h / $squareSize;
        $h_height = $squareSize / 2;
        $w_height = $squareSize / 2;

        if ($orig_w > $orig_h) {
            $adjusted_width = $orig_w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }

        elseif (($orig_w <= $orig_h)) {
            $adjusted_height = $orig_h / $wm;
            $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0,0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $adjusted_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }
    }

    if (@imagejpeg($virtual_image, $path2, 90)) {
        imagedestroy($virtual_image);
        imagedestroy($source_image);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

ini_set("memory_limit", "99M");
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
define('IMAGE_SMALL_DIR', '../../files/images/users/small/');
define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 50);
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR', '../../files/images/users/medium/');
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE', 250);
/*defined settings - end*/
if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file'])){
    $output['status']=FALSE;
    set_time_limit(0);
    $allowedImageType = array("image/gif",   "image/jpeg",   "image/pjpeg",   "image/png",   "image/x-png"  );

    if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
        $output['error']= "Error in File";
    }
    elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
        $output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
    }
    elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
        $output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
    } else {
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
        createDir(IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR);
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/$path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
        $fileType = $file["extension"];
        $desiredExt='jpg';
        $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
        $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
        $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;

        if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

            if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
                $output['status']=TRUE;
                $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
                $output['image_small']= $path[2];
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}








?>





















?>
```

Comment: something not working after AJAX success.

Comment: Please, format your code and remove empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var form_data =new FormData();` and append your uploaded file with the form_data obj.

```js
form_data.append('image_upload_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

Please check in form that you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for upload file.